# Open new window from GSP and forward to external URL

Tags: grails, struts

I need some help.  I am converting a Struts application to Grails.

There is a particular action I am trying to convert.

1. There is a form in a jsp that asks a user to select a customer from a dropdown list and the user clicks one of two buttons.
2. When the user clicks on the "View Reports" button, an onclick event calls a javascript function that issues window.open on a STRUTS action class, passing the selected customer and selected action.
3. In the action class the http request has some attributes set (request.setAttribute (..)) and a forward is performed to an external application.  The attributes that where set are used by the application for sign on. This is done as a POST.

My problem is I am not quite sure how to wire this flow using the Grails framework.  I was able to get as far as the user selecting a customer, clicking an actionSubmit button, reading the selected customer from params, adding my attributes to 'request' and then..I am stuck.

How to open a new window? (Tried javascript way as was done with Struts).

Also I am able to issue a redirect to the external site in the controller, however a redirect is done as a GET and not a POST, as well as the redirect is done in the same window.  Any help in laying this out would be awesome.  Thanks

Comment: So, you've tried a existing Javascript from Struts app, right? Did it work? What error did you get?

Comment: Yes the original application is in struts and working.  I am trying to accomplish the samething with GRAILS and need some direction.

Comment: And what happened with original Javascript? Why it doesn't work? any error or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect a user from server using POST.

**I can see some possible solutions:**

1 . If you don't need to pass through your server to validate or request some data, you can use this:

```
<form action="http://someotherserver.com" method="post">
```

2 . Create a controller that redirect to a page in your own site and in this page make a treatment that receives the paramters and then redirect the user to another domain using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

In Grails, I've used createLink, with the 'base' attribute to do this.

```
<g:createLink base="${params.dynamicURL}">Link</g:createLink>
```

I think something like this would work, but you can research it here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html